# Extract last word in string in R - error faced

Tags: string, extract, cpu-word

First, I wish to extract the last word and first word for the `Description` column (this column contains at least 3 words) into a newly created column `firstword` and `lastword`. However, the word() function is not applied to all the rows. As such, there are many rows with empty `lastword`, though these rows actually have a last word (as you can see from the `Description` column). This is shown in the first two lines of codes.

Second, I am also trying to get the third line of code to replace the `lastword` with `firstword`, if `lastword` is empty. However it isn't working.

Is there a way to rectify this?

```
c1$lastword = word(c1$Description,start=-1) #extract last word
c1$firstword = word(c1$Description,start=1) #extract first word
c1$lastword=ifelse(c1$lastword == " ", c1$firstword, c1$lastword)
```

[image: Screenshot of dataset - lastword still has missing values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that there is white space at the beginning of some of the rows of the `Description` variable, which isn't shown when viewed in R.

Removing the whitespace using `stri_trim()` solved the issue.

`c1$Description = stri_trim(c1$Description, "left")` #remove whitespace